# react-navigation: nested routing not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to achieve nested routing in the below example. But I am not able to navigate to "Other" route when I click on "Show me more of the app" button. Any help is appreciated.

https://snack.expo.io/rJYl02b6M

I know I can add Other to the parent StackNavigator but I need some common component and that is why I want to wrap the OtherSr=tack router with a component.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the live example. You just need to add:

```
Other: OtherStack,
```

to your `SwitchNavigator`.

So you'd have:

```
export default SwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack, 
    Auth: AuthStack,
    Other: OtherStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to have a common component that wraps the other router. So that I can have some logic that is common to all.